# Should I list ALL relevant skills in my resume?

Tags: resume

I am preparing a resume for a data-science/data-analysis role. In the Skills section, I'm listing the tools that I'm skillful at plus the skills. For example:

> Data Science tools: Python, Pandas, Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib, Seaborn,
>   Scikit-learn, SQL, BeautifulSoup, Selenium, Jupyter Notebook, R, NLTK,
>   Amazon Web Services (EC2, S3), etc.
>
> Data Science skills: Machine learning (regression and classification),
>   data visualization, ...

Should I list ***all*** the tools that I'm skillful at? For example, should I add XGBoost, LightGBM, tsfresh, Fabric, Boto3, etc. which are software packages I know (they are not as big packages as Scikit-learn for example, but they are powerful)? At what level of detail should I stop?

Comment: Are you tailoring your resume to suit the individual jobs you are applying for?

Comment: I don't have a specific job to apply for. I'm preparing the resume for any data-science or data-analysis role. When I find a specific job I want to apply for, I might tailor the resume to suit it

Comment: I wish I can understand the reason for downvoting the question! Just say so I know my mistake (if any)

Comment: This question is pretty similar to existing questions on the site that ask about the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can list the skills in three or two sections like Basic, Intermediate and Advanced.

You list them in those individual sections according to your expertise and knowledge.

It's also a good practice to include any relevant projects that you have completed that can show your understanding and skill in those relevant tools and languages.

Comment: I would advise against listing skills you don't want to use. When I graduated from college, I'd followed advise similar to this, but I listed *everything*, which included basic knowledge of several languages I'd only want to work with if that was the only work available to me. They didn't come up while I was doing my initial job search out of college, and I removed them from my resume. A year later, suddenly those skills were in high demand, and for three years my phone rang at least once most nights from a recruiter looking to hire me for something I abhorred.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't list out ALL of the Python modules you are proficient at. Those modules open up and allow for further flexibility in programming, but it's cluttered. How would you distinguish between what's necessary and superfluous? Something like: "Proficient in Python - highly qualified with data science modules working with graphs, database management, organization, natural language processing,and web-design. List of modules available upon request.

Now you are referencing the ability of the modules, yet you are not convoluting the resume with all the module names.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost everything, split into 2 sections - main skills (or tools or technologies) and additional skills.

These sections each have a 2 column table with the skill or tool and version in one column and the amount of experience (months/years) in the 2nd column.

```
SQL (including stored procs, triggers), PL-SQL, TSQL      25 years
Python (versions 1, 2, 4)                                 4  years
```

I sometimes prioritize (move to / from) skills in the main section, depending on the role.

Answer (score 1):

The two most important guidelines:

- Include only the ones that employers (especially the people whose job you are applying to) are likely to care about. For example, I have some experience as a lighting technician for theater, but it's not on my resume because none of the jobs I apply to are related to that at all.
- Only include skills that you'll be able to back up in a technical interview on your resume. If you include a technology that you're a total beginner in and can't really answer questions on, it'll make you look bad and the prospective employer may think that you're padding your resume. Or, at a minimum, if you're only a beginner in a technology and you insist on including it on your resume anyway, you should at least indicate that on the resume somehow to help avoid a potentially embarrassing situation in the interview. (No guarantees that it'll work 100% of the time, though - there's a chance that they'll ask anyway, in which case it could still look bad if you included a technology on your resume that you can't answer questions about).

With that said, I suspect that at least some of the packages you're talking about will fail at least one of the criteria I listed above.

Also, for long resumes, be aware there's a good chance that recruiters won't actually read the whole thing (at least not at first). One recent [eye tracking study](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/eye-tracking-study-among-recruiters-how-pass-initial-resume-eekman) found that recruiters spend, on average, 6 seconds doing an initial scan of a resume - mostly, they just look for the candidate name, employment start and end dates, and education. After that, maybe they spend a little bit of time skimming for relevant skills. It's *possible* that including the keywords would help with AI-based recruiting assistants, though.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking the answer to your question is "Yes" but what you actually write in your resume turns on the word "relevant".

Your potential employer has made clear, we assume, what they consider relevant. It is unlikely that that includes everything you have ever done that relates one way or another to the kind of job you imagine might be on offer.

You have to write a fresh resume for every job you apply for. In it you have to answer the only question the potential employer has in their mind: what can this person do for us? If your answer is a long list of courses taken, or languages mastered, then you are missing the point.